# Cannot Parent Armatures together with Different Armatures

Tags: modeling, bones

I have started to create more and more on blender, and after a long while coming, I finally manages to get to the point where I am experimenting with armatures.

However, after making my model and giving it some shape, I found that I can't parent the bone groups together to make the whole item on big model.

I have tried extruding fresh bones to join them to, but it doesn't seem to work.

https://pasteall.org/blend/7d72d859e91d49e4b87fce8e212cbbef

If you look at the model there are five tentacle and in need then to join to the main face.

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what you mean by "I found that I can't parent the bone groups together to make the whole item on big model"? You can upload your object here (once uploaded, copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange has a supported place to upload blend files that last for longer than the 6 months of pasteall.  If you want your blend file to remain with your question here's ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, if your question is about joining all the armatures into one armature and all the tentacles objects into one object, the current problem is that your bones, from an armature to another, have the same names, example: the first bone is always named *Bone*. When you'll join all the armatures together, each bone will be renamed so that you don't have 2 bones with the same name. The problem is that the mesh that have been parented to these bones still have the same vertex groups and therefore can't be controlled by bones that have now different names.

Maybe there's an smart solution to this problem (?), the tedious solution would be to join the armatures, rename the bones, join the tentacles objects, parent again to the armature *With Automatic Weights*.

Also, your tentacles are rather high poly and you have a lot of bones per tentacles, maybe, if you don't have any reason to keep this so complicated, you should simplify, you can even segment your bones to make them rounder. And you have scaled your armatures which may cause some unwanted deformations, apply the scale in *Object* mode.

Comment: Yeah. I like to add a lot of polys and then decrease them as i see fit. Also I am unsure if I can remove the bones because I really wanted to make sure he is a super bendy boi.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to add a lot of poly and then decrease. Also as I said you can segment your bones if you want them to be bendy (Bone Properties > Bendy Bones > Segments), you'll be able to see if you display your bones as bendy bones but it's not necessary